# Ajustar el tamaño a la pantalla BootStrap

Tags: css, bootstrap

Tengo un problema con visualizar un tablero en pantallas pequeñas o para móviles.

Le he puesto la clase **row** y dentro dos **divs** con **class**:

1. `class="col-sm-2" style="text-align:center; margin-top:2%"`
2. `class="col-sm-10" style="margin-top:2%"`

... y en ***CSS*** tengo puesto para la tabla:

```
.tablero{

    border-width: 4px;
    border-color: chartreuse;
}

table{

    margin: auto;        
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 10px solid;
    border-color: black;
}

td{

    background-color: #82E0AA;
    width: 175px;
    height: 175px;
    border: 5px solid;
    border-color: black;
}
```

En pantallas grandes, se visualiza bien, pero no sé cómo hacer para que en pantallas de teléfonos móviles, se vea el tablero entero.

¿Hay alguna manera de que se reajuste?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: pues es una tabla, con las tablas no tienes muchas opciones mas que achicar las letras y el tamaño de imagen

Comment: Me parece que va a ser la única opción, porque lo he intentado con las mediaqueries y se me queda todo igual

Comment: Edita tu pregunta, para poner el código que usaste de las @media ;)

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza media-queries de acuerdo a las medidas de los dispositivos móviles

//Tu ajustas las medidas 
//ejemplo de algunas resoluciones

```
    @media screen and (max-width:640px) {
        /* reglas CSS */
    }
    @media screen and (max-width:1024px) and (min-width:640px) {
        /* reglas CSS */
    }
    @media screen and (min-width:1024px) {
        /* reglas CSS */
    }
```

el tu caso configuras las medidas correspondientes de acuerdo cada max-width con cada una de tus clases algo así

```
 @media screen and (max-width:640px) {
       .tablero{


       }

       table{



       }

       td{


       }
    }
```

Comment: Lo he usado tambien, pero lo borré porque aun poniendole un tamaño fijo en cada medida con las mediaqueries, ni caso, y me da que es por el tamaño del contenido de dentro, aunque no tienen tamaño fijo.

Comment: a que te refieres con el contenido de dentro

Comment: el nombre de las calles y los divs que utilizo para poner las fichas y demás. Por ejemplo la imagen del centro

Comment: Te propongo agregar el código de la tabla en tu pregunta para poder apoyarte mejor

Answer (score 1):

Quizás te sirvan las `CSS @media Rule` ya que tus `td` tienen ancho fijo, por ejemplo puedes agregar a tu archivo `css` lo siguiente:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   td {
      width: 80px;
      height: 80px;
   }
}
```

Hay diferentes reglas que te permiten una adaptación diferente a cada tipo de pantalla.

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {...} 

/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {...} 

/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {...} 

/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {...} 

/* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {...}
```

Una guía muy completa hay aquí [Responsive Web Design - Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp), te recomiendo que la visites.

**Editado**
Podrías poner que tamaño de fuente tienen dentro de los `td`, ya que por más que quiera modificar su alto o ancho no te va a funcionar si la fuente es muy grande.

Saludos y espero que te sirva.